# How to reset single div using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drag-and-drop

Based on the dropdown value 3 or 4 I will show and Hide the div's. After showing content of Div it will be like this

[image]

I will drag and drop choice button into paragraph; for that I'm using code from the below fiddle.

```
http://jsfiddle.net/ChaseMoskal/T2zHQ/
```

The issue is that Onchange of dropdown show buttons. After that I can drag and drop once I dropped choice1.
If I move back to the same choice I can't get the Choice1 back. So I should reset choice div again. 
I tried with 
`.html()`,`.empty()`, and loading particular div, but its not working.

My HMTL:

```
<div class="choice col-md-10 col-md-offset-2">
  <div class="choices_butt3 box">
    <span class="fancy nonEditable">Choice1</span>
    <span class="fancy nonEditable">Choice2</span>
    <span class="fancy nonEditable">Choice3</span>
    </div>
    <div class="choices_butt4 box">
    <span class="fancy nonEditable">Choice1</span>
    <span class="fancy nonEditable">Choice2</span>
    <span class="fancy nonEditable">Choice3</span>
    <span class="fancy nonEditable">Choice4</span>
    </div>
        <div class="choices_butt5 box">
    <span class="fancy nonEditable">Choice1</span>
    <span class="fancy nonEditable">Choice2</span>
    <span class="fancy nonEditable">Choice3</span>
    <span class="fancy nonEditable">Choice4</span>
    <span class="fancy nonEditable">Choice5</span>
    </div>
        <div class="choices_butt6 box">
    <span class="fancy nonEditable">Choice1</span>
    <span class="fancy nonEditable">Choice2</span>
    <span class="fancy nonEditable">Choice3</span>
    <span class="fancy nonEditable">Choice4</span>
    <span class="fancy nonEditable">Choice5</span>
    <span class="fancy nonEditable">Choice6</span>
    </div>
     <div class="choices_butt7 box">
    <span class="fancy nonEditable">Choice1</span>
    <span class="fancy nonEditable">Choice2</span>
    <span class="fancy nonEditable">Choice3</span>
    <span class="fancy nonEditable">Choice4</span>
    <span class="fancy nonEditable">Choice5</span>
    <span class="fancy nonEditable">Choice6</span>
    <span class="fancy nonEditable">Choice7</span>
    </div>
     <div class="choices_butt8 box">
    <span class="fancy nonEditable">Choice1</span>
    <span class="fancy nonEditable">Choice2</span>
    <span class="fancy nonEditable">Choice3</span>
    <span class="fancy nonEditable">Choice4</span>
    <span class="fancy nonEditable">Choice5</span>
    <span class="fancy nonEditable">Choice6</span>
    <span class="fancy nonEditable">Choice7</span>
    <span class="fancy nonEditable">Choice8</span>
    </div>
    <div class="choices_butt9 box">
    <span class="fancy nonEditable">Choice1</span>
    <span class="fancy nonEditable">Choice2</span>
    <span class="fancy nonEditable">Choice3</span>
    <span class="fancy nonEditable">Choice4</span>
    <span class="fancy nonEditable">Choice5</span>
    <span class="fancy nonEditable">Choice6</span>
    <span class="fancy nonEditable">Choice7</span>
    <span class="fancy nonEditable">Choice8</span>
    <span class="fancy nonEditable">Choice9</span>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Can you please use the `<>` button and create a [mcve]. Also please read a little about English punctuation. There is always a space after a ,.!?:; and after .?!: the new word starts with a capital letter. See my edits

Comment: Please check this link http://jsfiddle.net/ChaseMoskal/T2zHQ/ Add tht Holo button dynmaically after that Is it working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store the html of the parent div in a variable on load, and while you want to reset the div you can just load the html content from the variable into the div.

Give an id for the parent container `id="choice_div"`

```
<div class="choice col-md-10 col-md-offset-2" id="choice_div">
```

Declare the variable as below and call the reset `resetChoicediv()` function onChange of Dropdown.

```
var choice_div_html;
function resetChoicediv(){
    $('#choice_div').html(window.choice_div_html);
}

$(function(){
    window.choice_div_html = $('#choice_div').html();
})
```

```css
.box {
  display:block;
  border:1px solid red;
  margin:5px;
}
.box span {
  display:block;
  padding:5px;
  border:1px dashed blue;
  margin:2px;
}
.removeBtn {
  color:red;
  float:right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <button type="button" onclick="resetChoicediv();">Reset DIV</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="addremovebuttons();">Add remove buttons</button>

</div>

<div class="choice col-md-10 col-md-offset-2" id="choice_div">
    <div class="choices_butt3 box">
        <span class="fancy nonEditable">Choice1</span>
        <span class="fancy nonEditable">Choice2</span>
        <span class="fancy nonEditable">Choice3</span>
    </div>
    <div class="choices_butt4 box">
        <span class="fancy nonEditable">Choice1</span>
        <span class="fancy nonEditable">Choice2</span>
        <span class="fancy nonEditable">Choice3</span>
        <span class="fancy nonEditable">Choice4</span>
    </div>
    <div class="choices_butt5 box">
        <span class="fancy nonEditable">Choice1</span>
        <span class="fancy nonEditable">Choice2</span>
        <span class="fancy nonEditable">Choice3</span>
        <span class="fancy nonEditable">Choice4</span>
        <span class="fancy nonEditable">Choice5</span>
    </div>
    <div class="choices_butt6 box">
        <span class="fancy nonEditable">Choice1</span>
        <span class="fancy nonEditable">Choice2</span>
        <span class="fancy nonEditable">Choice3</span>
        <span class="fancy nonEditable">Choice4</span>
        <span class="fancy nonEditable">Choice5</span>
        <span class="fancy nonEditable">Choice6</span>
    </div>
    <div class="choices_butt7 box">
        <span class="fancy nonEditable">Choice1</span>
        <span class="fancy nonEditable">Choice2</span>
        <span class="fancy nonEditable">Choice3</span>
        <span class="fancy nonEditable">Choice4</span>
        <span class="fancy nonEditable">Choice5</span>
        <span class="fancy nonEditable">Choice6</span>
        <span class="fancy nonEditable">Choice7</span>
    </div>
    <div class="choices_butt8 box">
        <span class="fancy nonEditable">Choice1</span>
        <span class="fancy nonEditable">Choice2</span>
        <span class="fancy nonEditable">Choice3</span>
        <span class="fancy nonEditable">Choice4</span>
        <span class="fancy nonEditable">Choice5</span>
        <span class="fancy nonEditable">Choice6</span>
        <span class="fancy nonEditable">Choice7</span>
        <span class="fancy nonEditable">Choice8</span>
    </div>
    <div class="choices_butt9 box">
        <span class="fancy nonEditable">Choice1</span>
        <span class="fancy nonEditable">Choice2</span>
        <span class="fancy nonEditable">Choice3</span>
        <span class="fancy nonEditable">Choice4</span>
        <span class="fancy nonEditable">Choice5</span>
        <span class="fancy nonEditable">Choice6</span>
        <span class="fancy nonEditable">Choice7</span>
        <span class="fancy nonEditable">Choice8</span>
        <span class="fancy nonEditable">Choice9</span>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    var choice_div_html;

    function resetChoicediv() {
        $('#choice_div').html(window.choice_div_html);
    }

    $(function() {
        window.choice_div_html = $('#choice_div').html();

        //adding remove buttons for each choice for testing...
        addremovebuttons();

    })

    //test - add remove btn
    function addremovebuttons() {
        $('#choice_div').find('span').each(function() {
            if ($(this).find('.removeBtn').length == 0) {
                $(this).append('<button onclick="$(this).parent().remove(); "class="removeBtn" >x</button>');
            }
        });

    }
</script>
```

Comment: what window means? @karthikeyan

Comment: `window` used here is to call the `choice_div_html` global variable, do you get any error.? You have to declare the variable and function globally, do not wrap it in `ready` function. only assign the variable `choice_div_html` value on dom ready.

Comment: There is no error.But its not working.Instaed it empty the div totally

Comment: This means the variable is empty..Can you check in your console what does $('#choice_div').html(); returns.. have you added Id for parent div..?

Comment: Ya I added And my console will show data inside div but when onchange it will empty

Comment: May be the html data is not being assigned to the variable..? what does the variable `choice_div_html` contain while onchange triggers? Please check the [working Jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/h1btw8Lt/)..check the added snippet in answer